# Replace string with new line with another string with new line

Tags: bash, macos, perl, sed, command-line

I need to run this from command line under Mac OS - I have multiple patterns.

From string:

```
</p>
<p>
```

To string:

```
</span>
<div>
```

I've tried this:

```
perl -pe 's:</p>\n<p>:</span>\n<div>:g'
```

but it fails on the text AFTER the newline `<p>`

Comment: It is by definition impossible to encounter `"</p>\n<p>"` when you are reading the file *line by line*. Given a file with those contents, your script will see `"</p>\n"` and `"<p>"`.

Comment: when I use this exact pattern in xCode search & replace then it works as needed. Why would not the same thing work from command line? There must be a way to search other then line_by_line.

Comment: "*There must be a way to search other then line by line*" ... There is ... But you are not using it. See @ysth's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search for a multiline string, you need to not be just reading one line at a time.

Try:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's:</p>\n<p>:</span>\n<div>:g'
```

See [-0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2A%2D0%2A%5B_octal%2Fhexadecimal_%5D)

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but it works:

```
sed '/^<\/p>$/{N;/<p>/{s/<\/p>\(\n\)<p>/<\/span>\1<div>/;p;d;};P;D;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this another solution, suppose if you don't want to slurp the whole file at a time,

```
perl -pe '$_.=<> if(/^<\/p>/); s:</p>\n<p>:</span>\n<div>:' input.txt
```

[@Sinan Ünür](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535839/replace-string-with-new-line-with-another-string-with-new-line/45540672#comments-45535839) mentioned his comment, as per comment you need to capture the next line if it is the current line having `<\p>`.

So the above code catching the next line and concatenating string with `$_` (`$_` already having the current line data) then substitute the pattern as per requirement.  Then no need to use `g` modifier in your regex.